# Are these .sql files in my edx output actually sql files?

Tags: mysql, sql, edx

As described here (http://edx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/internal_data_formats/package.html#data-package-contents), you can get certain event-tracking data about an edx course. Among these are some .sql files. But if I try importing these with MySQL Workbench, I jsut get an error. In addition, if I open them with Sublime, it looks like a tab-seperated-values file.

Aren't .sql files supposed to contain sql code? Why would edx be putting this extension on these files?

```
id  module_type module_id   student_id  state   grade   created modified    max_grade   done    course_id
461143  sequential  i4x://x/Class201x/sequential/56319fccf2c8480788fbb70e6938c094   2696554 {"position": 1} NULL    2015-05-10 02:29:39 2015-05-10 02:29:39 NULL    na  x/Class201x/3T2014
493905  sequential  i4x://x/Class201x/sequential/3968961bdfa948a89cfafa8aa06e7563   2696554 {"position": 1} NULL    2015-05-10 03:50:02 2015-05-10 03:50:03 NULL    na  x/Class201x/3T2014
```

Comment: can you post a sample of one?

Comment: here's one. since my question is one of format, it's a good representative

Comment: Yes, .sql would normally contain SQL, but this is just for convenience. You can put any extension on any file. The info linked to doesn't specify exactly whats in it. If it's tab separated then I guess you need to import it rather than running it in a SQL tool.

Comment: The linked docs say _Note that the .sql files are tab separated._. So, that just sounds like a misnomer of a file extension. File extensions are entirely arbitrary anyway, especially so for text files. It seems they just made a weird choice to call it .sql instead of .csv.